# Проблема с выводом в файл

Tags: c++, ооп, наследование

У меня 2 вопроса:

1. Как мне с метода `getWinner()` объекта `sportsmenArray` получить определенные данные одного конкретного спортсмена *(сейчас реализовано через костыль)*.
2. При выводе в файл `test.txt` помимо нужной информации появляются какие-то символы.

Собственно сам код:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define SIZE 10
#define DEBUG 10

using namespace std;

char* ptochar(int num){
    char str[8] = "";
    itoa(num, str, 10);
    return str;
}

template <class typeArray> class tArray{
protected:
    typeArray B[SIZE];
    int n;
public:
    tArray(int l){n=l;}
    void input(); 
    void output();
};
template <class typeArray > void tArray < typeArray >::input(){
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>B[i];
    }
}
template <class typeArray > void tArray < typeArray >::output(){
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cout<<B[i];
    }
}
class sportsmen{
#ifndef DEBUG
    int id;
    char surname[10];
    int result;
#endif //DEBUG
public:
#ifdef DEBUG
    int result;
    int id;
    char surname[10];
#endif //DEBUG
    int operator<(sportsmen ob2);
    friend ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, sportsmen ob); 
    friend istream &operator>>(istream &stream, sportsmen &ob);
    friend ofstream &operator<<(ofstream &stream, sportsmen ob);
    friend ifstream &operator>>(ifstream &stream, sportsmen &ob);
    void store(fstream &stream);
    void retrive(fstream &stream);
    };
    int sportsmen::operator <(sportsmen ob2){
    if(result<ob2.result)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

class sportsmenArray: public tArray<sportsmen>{
public:
    sportsmenArray(int l):tArray<sportsmen>(l){};
    void inputBFile(char* filename);
    void outputBFile(char* filename);
    void getWinner();
};
void sportsmenArray::outputBFile(char* filename){
    fstream out(filename, ios::out | ios::binary);
    if (!out){
        cout << "Cann't open file " << filename << " for output!" << endl;
        exit;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        B[i].store(out);
    }
    out.close();
}
void sportsmenArray::inputBFile(char* filename){
    fstream in(filename, ios::in | ios::binary);
    if (!in){
        cout << "Cann't open file " << filename << " for input!" << endl;
        exit;
    }
    for (int i=0;i<n;i++){
        B[i].retrive(in);
    }
    in.close();
}
void sportsmenArray::getWinner(){
    int max = B[0].result;
    int k=-1;
    for(int i=0; i < n; i++){
        if(B[i].result>max){
            max = B[i].result;
            k=i;
        }
    }
    cout <<
    "winner is:\nid: " << B[k].id <<
    "\tname: " << B[k].surname <<
    "\tresult: " << B[k].result << endl;
}

ostream &operator<<(ostream &stream, sportsmen ob){
    cout << ob.id << " \t " << ob.surname << " \t " << ob.result << endl;
    return stream;  
}
istream &operator>>(istream &stream, sportsmen &ob){
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Input id: ";       cin>>ob.id;
    cout << "Input Surname: ";  cin>>ob.surname;
    cout << "Input result: ";   cin>>ob.result;
    return stream;
}

ofstream &operator << (ofstream &stream, sportsmen ob){
    stream << ob.id << " " << ob.surname << " " << ob.result << endl;
    return stream;  
}

ifstream &operator >> (ifstream &stream, sportsmen &ob){
    stream >> ob.id;
    stream >> ob.surname;
    stream >> ob.result;
    return stream;
}

void sportsmen::store(fstream &stream){
    stream.write(ptochar(id),sizeof(int));
    stream.write(surname,sizeof(surname));
    stream.write(ptochar(result),sizeof(int));
}

void sportsmen::retrive(fstream &stream){
    stream.read(ptochar(id),sizeof(int));
    stream.read(surname,sizeof(surname));
    stream.read(ptochar(result),sizeof(int));
}


int main(){
    sportsmenArray C(3);
    C.input();
    C.outputBFile("test.txt");
    C.inputBFile("test.txt");
    C.output();
    C.getWinner();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: С чего вы взяли, что текущая реализация - это "костыль"? Вывод производится в бинарном режиме, поэтому не следует искать что-либо человекопонятное в файле. Кстати, что по-вашему делает `exit;` в `input`/`outputBFile`?

Comment: Я имею ввиду костыль добавления переменных класса как public, если убрать #define debug, то компиляция выдаст ошибку на свойствах класса спортсмен, к которым мы обращаемся в методе, но не имеем доступа

Comment: В этом случае, правильным подходом будет создание `getter`-ов, т.е. методов класса, которые будут возвращать значения полей (`getResult()` например будет возвращать значение `result`). [Getter](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%93%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80_(%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5)).

Comment: И это решит проблему с непонятными символами? Или кто позволит обратиться и приватным свойствам класса sportsmen?

Comment: К приватным свойствам класса позволит обратиться _открытый_ метод класса, который будет возвращать ссылку или значение нужного свойства